# Any ideas of how to group together objects from different hierarchies to create a new object

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I read somewhere that C++ OOPS way to program is "Build the objects in factory, Wire them in logic".

I am facing a application design problem. Consider there are several inheritance hierarchies as (with or without virtual functions):-

```
      Engine
        /\
       /  \
   Diesel Petrol
     /\      /\
    /  \    /  \
 2Cyl 4Cyl 2Cyl 4Cyl


       Audio
        /\
       /  \
 2Deck    4Deck



            Tyres
              /\
             /  \
        15Inch   17Inch
          /\       /\
         /  \     /  \
  tubeless Tube Tube Tubeless                     

  and more.... (System is scalable and new hierarchy may be added later on)
```

Now I have this application interface where 'Car' object is constructed in pick and choose style, like what Engine type ? What type of seats ? What type of Audio ? etc.

Any ideas, how do I design this system so that the 'Car' Object created is:-

1. Not tightly coupled to all parts hierarchies Supports addition of
   new hierarchies to already created cars: Say I have created a 'Car'
   object with tyres as tubeless and later in the Tyres hierarchy there
   is a new inheritance, I should be able to configure existing 'Car'
   object with new tyre type.

In other words, I like to leave the object hierarchy to class design, object creation to factory layer and wiring to logic layer.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, this looks like it could become what is commonly referred to as a Class Explosion. These can become a mainenance night-mare in no time at all.

From looking at your diagrams, several classes seem like they should be attributes, instead of actual classes. In the Tyre hierarchy, for example, why do you need 15Inch and 17Inch classes? What state or behavior do those classes offer? Why not put a size attribute on the Tyre class? Maybe even make it an enum. The same could probably be said for the 2Cyl, 4Cyl and 2Deck, 4Deck classes, although its hard to tell from the info presented.

In situations like this, its commonly good practice to prefer inclusion over inheritance when ever possible, which is commonly referred to as: prefer has-a relationships over is-a relationships. This is discussed in the [Strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_design_pattern), and you can find an excellent example in the [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) book.

I would suggest taking this advice into consideration and rethink your design.

Comment: The class hierarchy is for illustration purpose only. I am thinking on lines of using factory to create and wire them to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need a common class that all the hierarchies can share.

I would suggest a Part class.  These could be generated by the PartFactory.

The Car then is made up of Parts.